# Number of fragments in a Triangle

Tags: java, algorithm

How can i proceed to calculate the number of fragments in a **N** level Triangle 
[image]

fragment is a straight line that contains one or more match.

Comment: This is more a mathematics question than a programming question.   Compute a few values by hand, and try finding a general formula.  The result must be a multiple of three: start by counting the number of horizontal fragments, then multiply by 3 (same the two other orientations...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Notice that actually we can count the fragments for one orientation and multiply by 3 as they are symmetric (as shown as 3 different colors in the graph)

Let's count for one orientation:

Each level `x` has `x` matches, and we can choose `x` length 1 fragments, `x-1` length 2 fragments, `x-2` length 3 fragments ... and so on.

So for each level `x`, there is 1+2+3+...+x = x*(x+1)/2  fragments

So we can simply loop for all level `x` for one orientation, and multiply by 3.

Here is a sample C++ code:

```js
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int n, ans = 0;
int main() {
 cin >> n;
 for(int i=1; i<=n ;i++){
  ans += (1+i)*i / 2;
 }
 ans *= 3;
 cout << ans << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = n;
int con = 3;
int frag = 0;
for(int i =0; i<= n; i++)
{
frag += i*con;
}
return frag;
```

Comment: Thank's but this loop counts the number of matches, but a fragment can be composed by more than one matche, so for exemple for N = 2 Fragments = 12,  N = 4 Fragments = 60.

Answer (score 0):

notice that for a row of matches of size n, there are (n*(n+1))/2 (or n+1 choose 2) fragments. 
lets just think about the rows which are horizontal. we start from the smallest horizontal row (size 1) and go up to the largest horizontal row (size n). Thats how we construct our loop. Now notice that for the diagonally oriented rows, the number of fragments in them will be the same as the number of fragments in the horizontal rows.

Given there are three orientations with we can take the result of our loop and multiply it by 3. theres your answer.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sum += (i * (i + 1))/2;
}
sum *= 3;
```